# Декодирование json в php

Tags: json, php7

Есть json данные которые получаю с сервера

```
{"Data1":{"id":"smd/00816170582493857833","all_events":138,"successfully":130,"repeated":7}, "Data2":{"id":"smd/02535494217478907642","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data3":{"id":"smd/02871616724748330634","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data4":{"id":"smd/03835175092479613643","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data5":{"id":"smd/04196267776349243467","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data6":{"id":"smd/04446972944156247563","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data7":{"id":"smd/04594287625964267946","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data8":{"id":"smd/04721712271256933812","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data9":{"id":"smd/06103923827467606680","all_events":138,"successfully":136,"repeated":2}, "Data10":{"id":"smd/06323333259613843385","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data11":{"id":"smd/06445882044436085174","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data12":{"id":"smd/07605783873079346859","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data13":{"id":"smd/08542180024488807060","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data14":{"id":"smd/08898466308770135988","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data15":{"id":"smd/08942855905654126638","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data16":{"id":"smd/09831105186352560786","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data17":{"id":"smd/11121516891835927086","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data18":{"id":"smd/12003216147935909221","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data19":{"id":"smd/12131617651255374178","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data20":{"id":"smd/13270225561552577243","all_events":138,"successfully":134,"repeated":4}, "Data21":{"id":"smd/14153540525205008287","all_events":138,"successfully":136,"repeated":None}, "Data22":{"id":"smd/15465272135053609032","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data23":{"id":"smd/16510417255525683130","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data24":{"id":"smd/17832444770440256742","all_events":138,"successfully":124,"repeated":12}, "Data25":{"id":"smd/18165487606645530840","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data26":{"id":"smd/18240427650883280937","all_events":138,"successfully":134,"repeated":None}, "Data27":{"id":"smd/19860548429928228547","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data28":{"id":"smd/20001938013211076608","all_events":138,"successfully":136,"repeated":None}, "Data29":{"id":"smd/20031995118241079803","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data30":{"id":"smd/20716284525606810863","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data31":{"id":"smd/21278388182377101481","all_events":138,"successfully":7,"repeated":None}, "Data32":{"id":"smd/21861176378440036205","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data33":{"id":"smd/22793564597820185639","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data34":{"id":"smd/25023876531223323139","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data35":{"id":"smd/25141068182611547906","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data36":{"id":"smd/25234329847369629535","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data37":{"id":"smd/27762238274423555326","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data38":{"id":"smd/27788504236682305380","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data39":{"id":"smd/29391343674795642527","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data40":{"id":"smd/29464549470591411889","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data41":{"id":"smd/30398845807501160886","all_events":138,"successfully":70,"repeated":None}, "Data42":{"id":"smd/30586437414022103434","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data43":{"id":"smd/31393714653162678063","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data44":{"id":"smd/31429658098102769763","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data45":{"id":"smd/31657911124871283233","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data46":{"id":"smd/32949174780023081053","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data47":{"id":"smd/33102932739547937393","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data48":{"id":"smd/35938305255087337425","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data49":{"id":"smd/36304731628710232691","all_events":138,"successfully":128,"repeated":None}, "Data50":{"id":"smd/38274313089761680635","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data51":{"id":"smd/40649696890935294376","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data52":{"id":"smd/42154748996008246574","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data53":{"id":"smd/42202748509481957408","all_events":138,"successfully":86,"repeated":None}, "Data54":{"id":"smd/42476522883522823035","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data55":{"id":"smd/43060986190798668520","all_events":138,"successfully":129,"repeated":6}, "Data56":{"id":"smd/43487506155694957896","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data57":{"id":"smd/43536183103384845467","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data58":{"id":"smd/43750743778665431077","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data59":{"id":"smd/45158677566154087122","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data60":{"id":"smd/47223876621289746394","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data61":{"id":"smd/47965090983567314839","all_events":138,"successfully":134,"repeated":1}, "Data62":{"id":"smd/49004170882461072268","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data63":{"id":"smd/49855593623646838820","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data64":{"id":"smd/50230494140783717044","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data65":{"id":"smd/50882759561199303517","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data66":{"id":"smd/51302343358057354408","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data67":{"id":"smd/52683913419832324858","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data68":{"id":"smd/52908734634179699078","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data69":{"id":"smd/53479974528252270173","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data70":{"id":"smd/55804762553359628959","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data71":{"id":"smd/55995099483157429214","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data72":{"id":"smd/56026953006828266502","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data73":{"id":"smd/56327806294516093859","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":3}, "Data74":{"id":"smd/56386223091877353390","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data75":{"id":"smd/56408468426338467925","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data76":{"id":"smd/56581678855784808714","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data77":{"id":"smd/58495101034729972093","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data78":{"id":"smd/58640183605328518425","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data79":{"id":"smd/58720559704716351079","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data80":{"id":"smd/59147055801786250556","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data81":{"id":"smd/61836789403336529222","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data82":{"id":"smd/62438682005218752032","all_events":138,"successfully":136,"repeated":None}, "Data83":{"id":"smd/63352249529768003009","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data84":{"id":"smd/64145151176997343618","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data85":{"id":"smd/66124955067623861786","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data86":{"id":"smd/66377519577938694396","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data87":{"id":"smd/69351841909295355510","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data88":{"id":"smd/69762681178753417055","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data89":{"id":"smd/70187357186734755482","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data90":{"id":"smd/70662033415033390684","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data91":{"id":"smd/71671070830199731698","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data92":{"id":"smd/72594359409847687147","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data93":{"id":"smd/73154202255413219808","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data94":{"id":"smd/73172369110540998871","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data95":{"id":"smd/73307880106710525304","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data96":{"id":"smd/73762411897694477632","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data97":{"id":"smd/74614157182350685564","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data98":{"id":"smd/75393570815481967297","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":2}, "Data99":{"id":"smd/75879890722192378441","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data100":{"id":"smd/78944634188273016688","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data101":{"id":"smd/79041186146673111904","all_events":138,"successfully":None,"repeated":None}, "Data102":{"id":"smd/80010524761531622571","all_events":138,"successfully":133,"repeated":None}, "Data103":{"id":"smd/80231006067129840740","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data104":{"id":"smd/80437572191223825008","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data105":{"id":"smd/81330477903990656804","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":1}, "Data106":{"id":"smd/81726123182611041590","all_events":138,"successfully":134,"repeated":3}, "Data107":{"id":"smd/81829834921745447578","all_events":138,"successfully":133,"repeated":None}, "Data108":{"id":"smd/82412289197417241382","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data109":{"id":"smd/83936231428364802809","all_events":138,"successfully":137,"repeated":None}, "Data110":{"id":"smd/84327613310091220643","all_events":138,"successfully":None,"repeated":None}, "Data111":{"id":"smd/84748835880073066336","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data112":{"id":"smd/85020190962632611602","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data113":{"id":"smd/86344785055441157544","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data114":{"id":"smd/86417154121206377060","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data115":{"id":"smd/87166692851381046944","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":2}, "Data116":{"id":"smd/87573776009592517007","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data117":{"id":"smd/87898820762867293481","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data118":{"id":"smd/87962003659854685508","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data119":{"id":"smd/88027852401640574826","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":2}, "Data120":{"id":"smd/89071574908997381501","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data121":{"id":"smd/90188252421862073317","all_events":138,"successfully":136,"repeated":None}, "Data122":{"id":"smd/91197296090963380339","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data123":{"id":"smd/93916150407206340840","all_events":138,"successfully":136,"repeated":None}, "Data124":{"id":"smd/94233457775134351474","all_events":138,"successfully":135,"repeated":None}, "Data125":{"id":"smd/95022585457803045676","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data126":{"id":"smd/97146588434988884983","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data127":{"id":"smd/98836379256317082422","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data128":{"id":"smd/99014709512817528166","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "Data129":{"id":"smd/99743788009850879685","all_events":138,"successfully":138,"repeated":None}, "error":"false"}
```

При выполнении json_last_eror() возвращает JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX. Пробовал различные варианты по убиранию невидимых символов но они не работали, например

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $checkLogin = str_replace(chr($i), "", $checkLogin); 
}
$checkLogin = str_replace(chr(127), "", $checkLogin);

// This is the most common part
// Some file begins with 'efbbbf' to mark the beginning of the file. (binary level)
// here we detect it and we remove it, basically it the first 3 characters 
if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($checkLogin), 'efbbbf')) {
   $checkLogin = substr($checkLogin, 3);
}

$checkLogin = json_decode( $checkLogin );
print_r($checkLogin);
?>
```

Comment: Показанные вами данные не являются корректным json, так что и пытаться парсить их как json нет смысла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас невалидный JSON, вот на этом свойстве падает ошибка `"repeated": None`, *None* нужно обернуть в кавычки